# Swift 4 Copy arrays by value

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I have an array `var arr = [myObject]`
I want to copy it to `arr2` so that modifying object in the second the first remained as is (copy by value). How to make it?

Comment: I believe this was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066274/swift-how-to-copy-an-array-that-contains-reference-types

Comment: Your desired behaviour luckily is the default behaviour of Swift values types (e.g. Array). So whenever you assign an array to a new variable, you can modify it without affecting the original.

Comment: Not if the array contains reference types.

Comment: A proper answer depends on what you have in the array. Does your array contain classes. structs, or enums?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the type within your array is an enum or a struct, no problem. You don't need to think about it:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = a
b[1] = 3
b // [1, 3, 3]
a // [1, 2, 3]
```

If your array contains a class then you do need to think about how you copy objects, because by default you will be working with pointers to the same instances:

```
let ns = NSMutableArray()
var arr = [ns]
var arr2 = arr

arr2[0].add(2)
arr[0] // [2]
```

But where classes adopt the `NSCopying` protocol you can use copy() and mutableCopy() to make the necessary copies to resolve this:

```
var arr3 = arr.map(){$0.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray}
arr3[0].add(1)
arr3[0] // [2, 1]
arr[0] // [2]
arr2[0] // [2]
```

Where a class does not adopt the `NSCopying` protocol, you will need to extend or subclass, adding a `copy(with:)` method:

```
extension UIView: NSCopying {
    public func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return UIView(frame: self.frame)
    }
}

var aView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
var bView = aView.copy() as! UIView

aView.tag = 5
bView.tag // 0
aView.tag // 5
```

Note: The code example of copying a UIView is incredibly simplistic and assumes that a "copy" is simply a view the same size, whereas a copy in real use would be something more complex, most likely containing subviews, etc.

Answer (score 4):

actually the simplest way was to make:
 `var arr2:[myObject] =  Array(arr1)`

P.S. thanks to all for suggestions

Comment: let updatedMyArray:[MyObject] =  Array(self.MyArray) not wroking for me,

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a computed property. And then lazy load it to declare as a class variable.

```
lazy var secondArray :[myObject] = { return firstArray }()
```

Now if you ever need second array, it will get you first array